# How to dynamically change theme's slogan from admin?

Tags: themes, options

how can achieve this functionality. That I can change the themes "slogan" from admin and I don't have to go edit the themes source files.

I think that there is some theme options functionality. But how to use it and maybe somebody can point me to the correct path.

Added screenshot to clarify what I mean under slogan:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In wordpress that's a tagline..

maybe a plugin like this http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-tagline/ can help you.

Answer (score 1):

I just have this in my `function.php`file:

```
<?php
// Run the scripts for triggering the below functions
add_action('admin_menu', 'cms_options_menu');

function cms_options_menu() {
  //create new top-level menu
  add_menu_page('CMS options', __('CMS options'), 'administrator', __FILE__, 'cms_options_page',plugins_url('/images/icon.png', __FILE__));

  //call register settings function
  add_action( 'admin_init', 'register_custom_fields' );
}

function register_custom_fields() {
  //register our settings
  register_setting( 'cms-options', 'slogan' );
}

function cms_options_page() {
?>
  <form method="post" action="options.php">
    <table class="form-table">
      <tr valign="top">
        <td scope="row">
          <?php _e('Slogan'); ?>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="slogan" value="<?php echo get_option('slogan'); ?>" />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p class="submit">
      <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Changes') ?>" />
    </p>
  </form>
<?php } ?>
```

Then you just add whatever text you want and save the change.

Comment: And then what? How can I call it on the site? And where can I edit the slogan? I cant find any settings place in themes menu.

Comment: I've added the `add_action` function. Just put all this in the `function.php` file, and it should all work fine.

Comment: Ok, but where should the admin area appear? This is my first time ever, using wp..

Comment: I understand now, but for the record. `register_setting( 'cms-options', 'slogan );` there should be ' after slogan. Also, there is no submit button and it seems not to save the option.. it redirects it to some other option page.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the submit button. I've added it now - and fixed the typo :)

Comment: Yes, but as I stated before. It directs to /options.php url and basically, doesn't change the slogan..

Comment: `options.php` is a default file for WP. I don't know why the pages opens. If you click Settings in wp-admin and look at the source code, you will see the "same" form there. That's what I did. If my solution is not working, read the WP manual on how you can use `add_menu_page`, `register_setting` and custom fields in wp-admin and start from scratch. Good exersise to learn more about WP as well :)